# Как запретить программное изменение таба в PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я добавил вкладку (PropertyTab) в свой PropertyGrid и теперь должен сделать, чтобы при смене выделенного объекта эт вкладка не переключалась на "свойства".

Выбрал объект -> переключил таб в PG -> изменил объект -> таб вернулся на свойства.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно на клик по табу поместить в его в переменную, а потом при смене объекта вызвать из ToolStripButton PerformClick.